# Removing an ordered pair from a list of ordered pairs according to a certain criterion

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of ordered pairs produced by evaluating

```
{IsotopeData["Thorium226", "ExcitedStateEnergies"],
 IsotopeData["Thorium226", "ExcitedStateSpins"]}
```

I'm trying to remove all ordered pairs in the list of ordered pairs when the excited state spins is odd number. I am getting a empty list. Please help me.

Comment: `Transpose@Cases[Transpose@out, {_, x_ /; ! OddQ@x}]` where `out` is your list.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {IsotopeData["Thorium226", "ExcitedStateEnergies"], 
    IsotopeData["Thorium226", "ExcitedStateSpins"]} // Transpose;

(dataEven = Cases[data, {_, _?EvenQ}]) // Column
```

[image]

Some other alternatives

```
dataEven ==
 Select[data, EvenQ[#[[2]]] &] ==
 DeleteCases[data, {_, _?(! EvenQ[#] &)}] ==
 Pick[data, EvenQ[data[[All, 2]]]] ==
 GatherBy[data, EvenQ[#[[2]]] &][[1]] ==
 Gather[data, And @@ EvenQ[{#1[[2]], #2[[2]]}] &][[1]]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this, e.g.:

```
dat = Transpose@data;
Cases[dat, {_, _?EvenQ}]
Select[dat, EvenQ[Last@#] &]
Pick[dat, EvenQ@Last@# & /@ dat]
Extract[dat, Position[dat, {_, _?EvenQ}]]
```

All yield:

> {Quantity[72.20, "Kiloelectronvolts"],    2}, {Quantity[226.43,
>   "Kiloelectronvolts"],    4}, {Quantity[447.3, "Kiloelectronvolts"],
>   6}, {Quantity[721.9, "Kiloelectronvolts"],    8}, {Quantity[805.2,
>   "Kiloelectronvolts"],    0}, {Quantity[847.8, "Kiloelectronvolts"],
>   2}, {Quantity[1040.3, "Kiloelectronvolts"],    10}, {Quantity[1395.2,
>   "Kiloelectronvolts"],    12}, {Quantity[1781.5, "Kiloelectronvolts"], 
>   14}, {Quantity[2195.8, "Kiloelectronvolts"],    16}, {Quantity[2635.1,
>   "Kiloelectronvolts"],    18}, {Quantity[3097.1, "Kiloelectronvolts"],
>   20}}

Answer (score 2):

Your expression doesn't actually produce a list of ordered pairs, but rather two lists, one of excited spin energies and the other of excited spin states. Further, some the excited spin state values are missing and marked by `Missing["NotAvailable"]`. Presuming you not only wish to remove odd spins but missing ones too, I precede like so:

```
data = {ese, ess} = 
  {IsotopeData["Thorium226", "ExcitedStateEnergies"], 
   IsotopeData["Thorium226", "ExcitedStateSpins"]};
Extract[#, Position[ess, _?EvenQ]] & /@ data // Transpose
```

> ```
> {{72.2`4.keV, 2}, {226.43`5.keV, 4}, {447.3`4.keV, 6}, {721.9`4.keV, 8},
>  {805.2`4.keV, 0}, {847.8`4.keV, 2}, {1040.3`5.keV, 10}, {1395.2`5.keV, 12},
>  {1781.5`5.keV, 14}, {2195.8`5.keV, 16}, {2635.1`5.keV, 18}, {3097.1`5.keV, 20}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is one important method missing in the previous answers and which consists in replacing subparts of a list with (replacement) rules (see for example this official [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)).

By the way, you can also retrieve your data with this shorter syntax:

```
data=IsotopeData["Thorium226"][{"ExcitedStateEnergies", "ExcitedStateSpins"}]
```

Then

(for versions<**10.2** replace **`Nothing`** with **`Sequence[]`**)

```
Thread@data /. {_, spinState_?OddQ} -> Nothing
```

[image]

Every pair in the `Thread@data` list whose second element (`spinState`) is odd is replaced with `Nothing`.  As you can see, in the data I retrieved from the server there are missing spin state values (it seems the problem only concerns me ... ?) which have not been removed with this first replacement.

Actually, it gives the good opportunity to show how to easily chain multiple replacements to filter data:

```
Thread@data /. {_, spinState_?OddQ} -> Nothing /. {_, Missing[_]} -> Nothing
```

> [image]